# Getting internal server error 500.19

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Hi i try to run my aspx through iis 7.5 
 but i am gettimg this error

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information 
Module
IIS Web Core 
Notification
BeginRequest 
Handler
Not yet determined 
Error Code
0x80070032 
Config Error
The configuration section 'log4net' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration  
Config File
\\?\C:\Synxis\trunk\ProjectX\Synxis\Application\Interfaces\Interface\web.config 
Requested URL
http://localhost:80/Interface/Oxi.aspx 
Physical Path
C:\Synxis\trunk\ProjectX\Synxis\Application\Interfaces\Interface\Oxi.aspx 
Logon Method
Not yet determined 
Logon User
Not yet determined 
Config Source   420: 
  421:   <log4net>
  422:
```

can someone please sort me out of this?
web.config`

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains not just the error but the code.

Answer (score 1):

Without code this is a shot in the dark, but did you put an entry in the  part of your config file?  Similar to the following...

```
<configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: adding it is not working anyway thanks it is not allowing me to enter the complete code it is too big